# Google Maps for Android does not immediately display the map, and loads slowly

Tags: android, google-maps

Google Maps on Android is not immediately displaying the map, and once it begins to display it loads slowly, starting with a black screen. Loading steps are shown in the screenshot below;

[image]

How can I improve the speed that Google Maps downloads data?

Comment: How much time is `a while`?

Comment: loading takes 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Android API v2 downloads map tiles from Google servers, so you can't have them immediately. It all depends on the connection speed.

For a black screen check [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639).